# Отдать статику с динамических поддоменов nginx

Tags: nginx, static

Всем доброго времени суток.

Имеется следующая ситуация.
На сервере поднят сервис на pm2(node.js), который представляет из себя proxy, при этом имеет место внедрение нашего скрипта в html
- Поднят nginx со следующей конфигурацией

```sh
server {
    server_name *.proxy.mydomain.com;
    root /path/to/proxy/source;

    index index.html;

    proxy_buffer_size   64k;
    proxy_buffers   4 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size   64k;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Внедрение скрипта происходит путем вставки

```html
<script src="..."></script>
```

в `</head>`

Нужно настроить nginx на отдачу статики, а точнее того самого скрипта для внедрения.

Comment: Ничего не понятно, с чем трудности возникают и при чём тут динамический поддомен? Пишите нужный вам location и прописывайте в нём любые нужные вам настройки статики, что мешает?

Comment: В моем понимании `server_name *.proxy.mydomain.com;*` - динамические поддомены. При попытке настроить nginx следующим образом `location /file.js: { root /public/file.js}` выдается 404

Comment: Потому что root никогда не может указывать на файл и должно быть `root /public;` и динамические поддомены тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: `root /public/` тоже 404

Comment: Читайте в логе ошибок nginx, почему он выдал ошибку 404

Comment: Спасибо - ошибка с моей стороны в написании пути))